# How to group API calls in a middleware nodejs application?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to write a nodejs script that communicates with the server, with the number of tasks as a comma-separated string ("1, 2, 3") in the URI. The thing is, I am getting 414 for many tasks. I am not able to think to come up with a solution. How to batch process it? Like for each and every 50 ids, the API should be called like `api/${1, 2, ... 50}` and `api/${51, 52, ... 100}`

My API call is:

```
const patchProducts = async (ids) => {
  try {
    await axios.patch(`api/${ids}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Pass the ids in the request body instead of in the URL?

Comment: Its a kind of external API. I am not able to control it

Comment: In that case, all you can do is limit the length of the URL. To how much depends on what that remote API is willing to accept.

Comment: Yea. How do I group the ids and make the API call? If I have 100 ids, I want to do like 2 API calls like `api/${1, 2, 3 ..., 50}` and `api/${51, 52, ..., 100}`. How can I do like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the list of ids into lists of (say) 50 items at most, and process each separately:

```
const patchProducts = async (ids) => {
  const arr = ids.split(', ');
  try {
    while (arr.length) {
      const batch = arr.splice(0, 50);
      await axios.patch(`api/${ batch.join(', ') }`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: getting ids.splice is not a function. ids is a comma separated string btw

Comment: @Whiz see edit.

Comment: Man you just saved my life. Thank you so much =D